# MessageBox not providing expected DialogResult

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialogresult

I have a simple OK/Cancel `DialogResult` instance within my form:

```
MessageBox.Show("Number of records affected:" + numberOfRecordsroll + " Please check the data is correct before proceeding:", "Please validate your changes", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // CommitTheChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("test", "test");
}
else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    //Do nothing
}
```

As you can see if the user clicks yes the method `CommitTheChanges` should be called, however this was not firing. I have since commented it out and placed a test `MessageBox.Show()`. Again this is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just creating a new DialogResult and ignoring the click from the dialog. Instead you need to get the DialogResult from the MessageBox

```
 String msg = "Number of records affected:" + numberOfRecordsroll + " Please check the data is correct before proceeding:";
 DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(msg, "Please validate your changes", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've compared the result of `dr` which is a new instance of `DialogResult` it has no reference to the current `MessageBox`.

You need to assign the current message box `DialogResult` to dr.

```
DialogResult dr;

dr = MessageBox.Show("Number of records affected:" + numberOfRecordsroll + " Please check the data is correct before proceeding:", "Please validate your changes", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                       // CommitTheChanges();
                        MessageBox.Show("test", "test");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the `new` keyword.

When using `new` as an operator on a `reference type` you're immediately creating a new object on the heap and the one resulting from the `MessageBox` is now ripe for collection by the Garbage Collector. In fact, in this case you are not even capturing the `DialogResult` from the `MessageBox`.

Something like this will work:

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Number of records affected:" + numberOfRecordsroll + " Please check the data is correct before proceeding:", "Please validate your changes", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
{
    CommitTheChanges();
}
```